# Click two times to get source attribute in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am trying to get an image on the right side when I click on my custom dropdown. When I click on any option, it will get an image from that particular option and get the src attribute of that option image tag. It then shows that image.

When I click on the option, it gets the source attribute, but I have to click two times to show a different image when I click on any option.

JavaScript here:

```
<script language="javascript">
function getCarBrand(li){
    var x = li.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].textContent;
    document.getElementById("car_brand").value = x;
    var y = document.getElementById("car_brand_id_img").src;
    document.getElementById("img_car").src = y; 
    document.getElementById("img_car").style.display = 'block';        
}
</script> 
<html>
<!-- for car brand -->
     <label for="Vehicle">Select Your Vehicle/Make</label>
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-6">
             <div class="mm-dropdown">
                 <a href="#" id="vehicle_brand">SELECT YOUR VEHICLE 
                   BRAND<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
                    <ul id="vehicle_brand_id" >

    <?php 
    $query1 = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM `vehicle`");

    if (mysqli_num_rows($query1)> 0){           
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1)){
               $car_id=$row['id'];
               $name=$row['name'];
               $img = $row['image'];
     ?>
 <li onclick="getCarBrand(this)" data-value="1">
     <img src="asset/img/<?php echo $img; ?>" alt="" width="20"     height="20" id="car_brand_id_img"  />
     <span><?php echo $name; ?></span>
                              </li> 
                          </ul>
<input type="text" id="car_brand" name="Vehicle_brand" value="" />
<input type="text" id="car_b" name="Vehicle_brand" value=""/>                   
     </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <img src="" id="img_car" height="100" width="100" style="display: none;"/> 
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: your html structure is wrong. a minimal example is: `<html><body> everything goes here, scripts go last </body></html>`

Comment: `id`s should be unique across the document, you are reusing the same `car_brand_id_img` inside the loop

Comment: don't bother about html structure kindly solve my query

Comment: the problem is that when i select any option form options i have to click two times to show image

Comment: Yes I tried but the problem is still there

Answer (score 0):

Having duplicated `id`s in your document, as `car_brand_id_img` is going to cause problems when calling `getElementById` since this behavior is undefined. You can select by tag name or class or assign a unique id to each car image. You can limit the search to the triggered element and get the correct `id`, but since it's highly discouraged I'm going with the other approach. Reduced example:

```js
function getCarBrand(li) {
  var x = li.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].textContent;
  var y = li.querySelector("img").src;
  console.log(y); // Now it gets the desired element every time
  document.getElementById("car_brand").value = x;
  document.getElementById("img_car").src = y;
  document.getElementById("img_car").style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<!-- for car brand -->
<label for="Vehicle">Select Your Vehicle/Make</label>

<a href="#" id="vehicle_brand">SELECT YOUR VEHICLE BRAND<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
<ul id="vehicle_brand_id">
  <li onclick="getCarBrand(this)" data-value="1">
    <img src="asset/img/img1.jpg" alt="1" width="20" height="20" id="car_brand_id_img" />
    <span>Car 1</span>
  </li>
  <li onclick="getCarBrand(this)" data-value="1">
    <img src="asset/img/img2.jpg" alt="2" width="20" height="20" id="car_brand_id_img" />
    <span>Car 2</span>
  </li>
</ul>
<input type="text" id="car_brand" name="Vehicle_brand" value="" />
<input type="text" id="car_b" name="Vehicle_brand" value="" />

<div class="col-lg-6">
  <img src="" id="img_car" height="100" width="100" style="display: none;" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for helping me can you give me skype id for further query.